# Python displays data as errorbar in barplot

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, errorbar

I would like to make a barplot of my dataframe 'top30_art' that looks like this:

```
,artikelenlijst,count
0, artikel 14 van de Grondwaterwet,40
1, artikel 6.4 van de Waterwet,23
2, artikel 14 van de Grondwaterwet,17
3, artikel 6 van de Wbm,17
4, artikel 7 van de Wet op de waterhuishouding,16
5, artikel 1:2 van de Awb,15
6, artikel 4:84 van de Awb,14
7, artikel 7 van de Wet op de waterhuishouding,14
etc.
```

In my plotting code, I use the following:

```py
sns.barplot(x='count', y='artikelenlijst', 
            data=top30_art,label="frequency", color='r')
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: first plot]

However, as you can see, it is plotting a part of the data as an error bar. For example: the first row of my count column should be `40` (see the number above), but somehow Python displays only a barplot for a count of 28 and an error bar to display the rest of the count from 28 to 40 in my plot.

To fix this error, I tried to add `ci='None'`:

```py
sns.barplot(x='count', y='artikelenlijst', data=top30_art,label="frequency", color='r', ci=None)
```

This results in the new following plot:

[image: second plot]

Then you don't see the error bar anymore but it still does not display the right number for the first row: now the bar ends at 28, but it should end at a count of 40.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Seaborn shows an errorbar each time one individual y value (for the horizontal bars) appears more than once.  It then will show the mean by the full bar, and an errorbar indicating "95% confidence interval". So, apparently, you have at least two rows with `"artikel 14 van de Grondwaterwet"`.

Comment: If you just want to show the bar plot as the pure data, you can use `ax = sns.barplot(x='count', y=top30_ar.index, data=top30_ar, orient='h')` followed by `ax.set_yticks(top30_ar.index, top30_ar['artikelenlijst'])`.